# how to create db2 schema with password by command

Tags: db2, database-schema

I am creating db2 schema by using **create schema schemaName** in mydb database, now while I connect the database by writing **connect to mydb user schemaName;**
 it prompts to give a password. 
My question is how to **set a password** to my existing schema in db2 database

Comment: Rather than setting a password for the schema, consider setting authorities. A user's password allows connection; authorities allow a user actually to do some actions such as reading database schema content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A schema cannot have a password. A *user* can have a password, but the *user* does not necessarily match any *schema*. In DB2 authentication is delegated to the operating system (or other external authority), so you need to use whatever password belongs to the operating system user "schemaName".

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Now I have understand the matter and my issue is solved..